# Windows forms application random math game c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am having problems with putting a max number of question limit I'm new to windows forms so I tried a  changing the textbox of the questions number text box to int then putting a loop using (while();) but the program just freezes + how do I tell the user answer if his answer is right or wrong using (if) didn't work for me I don't know where to put it or if my way of changing the text box to int is right here is my code.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       
        public Form1()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();
            
            numrange.Items.Add("1,100");
            numrange.Items.Add("1,500");
            numrange.Items.Add("1,1000");
            operation.Items.Add("+");
            operation.Items.Add("-");
            operation.Items.Add("*");
            operation.Items.Add("/");

       
           
           
       
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        int[] Rand(int v)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.Next(1,v);
        int b = r.Next(1,v);
            int[] N = { Math.Max(a,b) , Math.Min(a,b)};
            return N;

        }
        void generate()
        {
        


            int range = 0;
            switch (numrange.SelectedIndex)
            { 
                case 0:
                    range = 100;
                    break;
                case 1:
                 range = 500;
                   break;
                case 2:
                    range = 1000 ;
                   break;
               default :
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Insert a range!!");
                    break;
            
            
            }
            int[] Numbers = Rand(range);
            int numofquest = Convert.ToInt32(maxquestion.Text);
            int numofquestleft;
            numofquestleft = numofquest;
            while (numofquest > 0)
            {


                switch (operation.SelectedIndex)
                {


                    case 0:
                        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ", Numbers[0], Numbers[1]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} - {1} = ", Numbers[0], Numbers[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} * {1} = ", Numbers[0], Numbers[1]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1} = ", Numbers[0], Numbers[1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show("Please insert an operation!!");
                        break;

                }
                numofquestleft--;
            }
            }

        private void Startbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generate();
            
           
        }

        private void Nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generate();
        }
        
        
        
        
        }
    }
        
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the approaches that freeze/didn't work

Comment: i edited my question and put in the code that freeze and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt change `numofquest` in the `while` loop, therefore `numofquest > 0` is always true.
It should be `while numofquestleft > 0`. Be sure it;s **numofquestleft** and not **numofquest**

Aside from that, if you want to generate a different question each time you hit the button, consider putting the `generate()` with no loop inside the clickfunction, a loop will run all in one go. Something like this:

```
private int numofquestleft;
private int answer;

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numofquestleft = Convert.ToInt32(maxquestion.Text);
    
    if (numofquestleft > 0) generate();
    numofquestleft--;
}

private void Nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Convert.ToInt32(userinput.Text) == answer){ MessageBox.Show("Correct");}
     else {MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");}

     if(numofquestleft > 0) generate();
     numofquestleft--;
}
```

To check user's answer, first calculate the result:

```
switch(operation.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ",Numbers[0],Numbers[1]);
        answer = Numbers[0] + Numbers[1];
        break;
    case 1:
        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} - {1} = ",Numbers[0],Numbers[1]);
        answer = Numbers[0] - Numbers[1];
        break;
    case 2:
        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} * {1} = ",Numbers[0],Numbers[1]);
        answer = Numbers[0] * Numbers[1];
        break;
    case 3:
        questionbox.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1} = ",Numbers[0],Numbers[1]);
        answer = Numbers[0] / Numbers[1];
        break;
}
```

Then compare it with user input (convert to int), assuming when you hit Next:

```
private void Nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Convert.ToInt32(userinput.Text) == answer){ MessageBox.Show("Correct");}
     else {MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");}

     if(numofquestleft > 0) generate();
     numofquestleft--;

}
```

This will check the answer of a question, then generate a new question when you click Next.

Comment: i did it but the loop won't stop after numofquest is < 0 plus can I ask you a question, my question box is a string how can I check if the user answer is right or not thanks

Comment: i got a red line under maxquestion.Text I put it right where you said + what do you mean by case I tried typing .getText it won't show up